# Unexpected End of Stream when using MariaDB in BlueMix

Tags: mysql, mariadb, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

we are having a problem in our applications deployed in BlueMix. It only happens after a couple of days without using them. The first request throws the exception pasted bellow. It looks like BlueMix "freezes" MariaDB when detects no activity and so the first request is lost. It's a problema as first time user goes to the App or performs a call (it's a voice application) the page or call is lost with an error.

Any idea on how to avoid this? (Would like to avoid including a thread to make a query every 5 mins as a workaround)

Also, any recommended free alternative to MariaDB offering in BlueMix (We are very used to use SQL as persistent provider to JPA+Hibernate) so would like to stick to that for now.

Thanks

```
 [10/16/15 8:00:12:085 UTC] 000234d6 com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionEventListener                      A J2CA0056I: The Connection Manager received a fatal connection error from the Resource Adapter for resource jdbc/ElizaCCDS. The exception is: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4:org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.common.QueryException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4:java.io.EOFException: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
 [10/16/15 8:00:12:093 UTC] 000234d6 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl                 E DSRA0304E:  XAException occurred. XAException contents and details are: The cause is               : null.
 [10/16/15 8:00:12:093 UTC] 000234d6 com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl                 E DSRA0302E:  XAException occurred.  Error code is: UNKNOWN XA EXCEPTION CODE (0).  Exception is: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
 [10/16/15 8:00:12:094 UTC] 000234d6 com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources                      E WTRN0078E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call start on a transactional resource has resulted in an error. The error code was XA_OK. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.mapXAException(MySQLXAResource.java:43)
     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.execute(MySQLXAResource.java:51)
     at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.start(MySQLXAResource.java:151)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.start(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1189)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.start(XATransactionWrapper.java:1281)
     at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAResourceBase.start(JTAResourceBase.java:157)
     at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.startRes(RegisteredResources.java:1000)
     at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.enlistResource(RegisteredResources.java:642)
     at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.enlistResource(TransactionImpl.java:2359)
     at com.ibm.tx.jta.embeddable.impl.EmbeddableTranManagerSet.enlist(EmbeddableTranManagerSet.java:157)
     at com.ibm.ws.transaction.services.TransactionManagerService.enlist(TransactionManagerService.java:370)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.enlist(XATransactionWrapper.java:596)
     at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.ConnectionManager.lazyEnlist(ConnectionManager.java:2165)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.lazyEnlist(WSRdbManagedConnectionImpl.java:2181)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.beginTransactionIfNecessary(WSJdbcConnection.java:493)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2188)
     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcConnection.prepareStatement(WSJdbcConnection.java:2154)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
     at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
     at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
     at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
     at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
     at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
     at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
     at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
     at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
```

Let me add a new stack trace:

```
    [App/0]ERR at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.mapXAException(MySQLXAResource.java:43)
[App/0]ERR at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.execute(MySQLXAResource.java:51)
[App/0]ERR at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLXAResource.start(MySQLXAResource.java:151)
[App/0]ERR[ERROR ] WTRN0078E: An attempt by the transaction manager to call start on a transactional resource has resulted in an error. The error code was XA_OK. The exception stack trace follows: javax.transaction.xa.XAException: Could not read resultset: unexpected end of stream, read 0 bytes from 4
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
[App/0]ERR at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4126)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:137)
[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.spi.WSRdbXaResourceImpl.start(WSRdbXaResourceImpl.java:1189)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ejb.EJSLocalNSGApplicationManagerBean_04c55490.getBooleanPropertyValue(EJSLocalNSGApplicationManagerBean_04c55490.java)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:991)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:213)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ejb.ApplicationManagerBean.getPropertyValue(ApplicationManagerBean.java:227)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2587)
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.servlet.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:44)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1068)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.servlet.ServengineWebFilter.doFilter(ServengineWebFilter.java:144)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:201)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:186)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ejb.ApplicationManagerBean.getProperty(ApplicationManagerBean.java:179)
[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
[App/0]ERR at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:66)
[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ejs.container.EJSContainer.invokeProceed(EJSContainer.java:5323)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.application.ejb.ApplicationManagerBean.getBooleanPropertyValue(ApplicationManagerBean.java:279)
[App/0]ERR at org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.resolver.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:179)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[App/0]ERR at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
[App/0]ERR at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPATxEmInvocation.find(JPATxEmInvocation.java:215)
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1106)
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:257)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.find(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1110)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:503)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:102)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2000(SessionImpl.java:176)
[App/0]ERR at com.servengine.openid.OpenIDLoginView.isOpenIDEnabled(OpenIDLoginView.java:123)
[App/0]ERR at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:98)
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:468)
[App/0]ERR at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
[App/0]ERR at [internal classes]
```